# AWS QLDB Delete Record and its Revision History

Tags: revision-history, amazon-qldb

We are looking into using AWS QLDB to store some data that will remain in QLDB for a few months but then we want to move untouched data into AWS Glacier. Is it possible to completely remove the record and its revision history from a QLDB table such that there is no record of it ever being there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QLDB is an append only, immutable ledger database. It is only possible to remove document from [user and committed view](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ledger-structure.html#ledger-structure.querying). The revisions would still be there in the [history table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/working.history.html) and the journal storage.

Comment: Maybe this is interesting for everyone here: Data Redaction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnaUCg2XhSw useful in the sense of GDPR